# Как получить имя объекта, который обратился к методу?

Tags: c#, методы, label

Есть метод `ColorChange`, который меняет цвет `label`... у него есть два параметра

```
public void ColorChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Как мне получить имя объекта который обратился к методу?

Comment: что такое "имя объекта"?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Если знаете, что обращается какой то там Button или ещё кто, то `var button = (Button)sender;` Ну и получите все параметры нужной кнопки, включая имя. `button.Name`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, ваш ответ мне очень помог!

Comment: @Arthur_Zhilinskiy Давайте тогда закроем вопрос. Сейчас ответом оформлю это, примите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При подписывание на событие вы создаёте метод, который выполняется. В вашем случае это `public void ColorChange(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Внутрь обычно передаётся 2 значения, один из которого - `sender`, это объект, который отвечает за то, кто именно инициализировал это событие.

Так вот, если мы этот объект `sender` приведём к нужному типу, то мы сможем получить необходимые значения (имя, тег, контент и др.). Как же задать тип?:

1. `var button = (Button)sender` - тут мы указали, что `sender` является у нас кнопкой. Но, тут надо не забывать проверять полученный `button` на `Null`, иначе дальше могут быть проблемы. То есть мы должны указать что то вроде `if (button != null)`.
2. `if (sender is Button button)` - тут мы указываем тип и заодно и делаем проверку на `Null`, удобно и коротко. Но на старых версиях языка вроде данный метод не работает.